# How do I ensure I am using MIT-licensed code correctly?

Tags: licensing, mit, derivative-works

This might be silly question but I thought its best I thought I should clear this up.

I found [this repositoy](https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort) on Github. It has a MIT license attached to it and I modified this repository according to my needs.

I want to know that do I have to apply for a license to use this code or can I use it without acquiring the license as I'm planning to use/sell it.

If I have to acquire it's license then how should I do it? Please give the method as well.

Comment: Have you read the MIT license, and which bits of it did you find difficult to understand?

Comment: For this repository, I read the license, it says, that it free to use for personal/patent use with no liability and warranty. I want to use this code with my modifications. So I'm asking do i need to ask the licensor to give me the license or apply for the license, for this code so that I can use it? Or i can just use it directly?

Comment: In simple words, I'm asking that do i need to inform someone or go through a procedure that I'm using there code?

Comment: It's not "free for *personal* use" (that wouldn't qualify as free software/open source), it's free for **any** use.

Comment: @PrithviRajKanaujia the word "personal" does not exist in the license nor does the word "patent" a single time. Which license did you read?

Comment: I read the MIT license attached with that github repository. Well it could be a mistake from my side in framing the sentence. I was trying to express my intentions that I have.

Answer (score 3):

Hope you have read the license included in the repository .

> I want to know that do I have to apply for a license to use this code or can I use it without acquiring the license as I'm planning to use/sell it.

Yes , You are permitted to use it without acquiring any  explicit license. But you have to include the copy right notice as they have clearly stated in the license.

for more clarity on what it means please check https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/178486/what-exactly-does-the-condition-in-the-mit-license-imply

Comment: okay.. Thank you for your response. I will surely check the link